# extract text from alphanumeric vector in R

Tags: r, string, extract

i have a data like below and need to extract text comes before any number. or if we can separate the text and number then it would be great

```
df<-c("axz123","bww2","c334")
```

output

```
"axz", "bww", "c"
```

or

```
"axz","bww","c"
"123","2","334"
```

Comment: See `help("regmatches")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do:

```
df <- c("axz123","bww2","c334")
gsub("\\d+", "", df)
#[1] "axz" "bww" "c" 
gsub("(\\D+)", "", df)
#[1] "123" "2"   "334"
```

For your other example:

```
df <- "BAILEYS IRISH CREAM 1.75 LITERS REGULAR_NOT FLAVORED"
gsub("\\d.*", "", df)
#[1] "BAILEYS IRISH CREAM "
gsub("[A-Z_ ]*", "", df)
#[1] "1.75"
```

Comment: Thanks Alot..it worked.can i ask you for a fever ? where i can learn this trick on gsub(). like when to use "D+" or "d" etc. because i do face similar problems frequently. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `[:alpha:]` to match the alphabetic characters, and combine this with `gsub()` and a negation to remove all characters that are not alphabetic:

```
gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", df)
#[1] "axz" "bww" "c"
```

To obtain only the non-alphabetic characters we can drop the negation `^`:

```
gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", df)
#[1] "123" "2"   "334"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input its quick but the problem is bit tricky, i have data like "BAILEYS IRISH CREAM 1.75 LITERS REGULAR_NOT FLAVORED" and the output needed is "BAILEYS IRISH CREAM" and "1.75". sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @NitinPatil That should be a different question.  Please don't post a simple example and expect others to give answers for your complex data.  Even in the new string, there are spaces.  So, totally different question.

Comment: @akrun: i apologize for the confusion, i was just trying to simplify the stuff

Comment: @NitinPatil No problem.  I understand that you were trying to help with an example.  But, with regex, everything depends on the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract` and regex lookarounds.  We match one or more characters before any number (`(?=\\d)`) and extract it.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df, "[[:alpha:]]+(?=\\d)")
#[1] "axz" "bww" "c"
```

---

If we need to separate the numeric and non-numeric, `strsplit` can be used

```
lst <- strsplit(df, "(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE)
```